# Swift: Type does not confirm to protocol 'BooleanType.Protocol'

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error when trying to check if an optional variable is set or not.

`Error: Type CGPoint? does not confirm to protocol 'BooleanType.Protocol'`

This is my code:

```
var point : CGPoint?

if (point) {
   ...
}
```

Isn't this how optional types in Swift are supposed to be used?

How should the if-comparison be written?

Comment: This is why you should read the release notes whenever a new Xcode Beta comes out - all this and more is described in there.

Comment: @Anorak It seems to me that they override beta release notes, so now we're at beta 6 and notes for beta 5 aren't available anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since beta 5, you should write `point == nil` or `point != nil`.

This change was made because of confusion when the value was an optional boolean.
For example:

```
let maybe : Bool? = false
if maybe {
    // executed because `maybe` is an optional having a value (false),
    // not because it is true
}
```

You can also use the conditional assignment as before:

```
if let assignedPoint = point { 
    /* assignedPoint is now a CGPoint unwrapped from the optional */ 
}
```